# github, test workflow in branch

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

If I create a feature branch that has changes to workflow, is there a way to test it before merge? I have added on pull request to workflow but it has no effect.

Comment: The workflow being run should be the one in your feature branch if you use `pull_request` (and not `pull_request_target`) as the trigger.

Comment: It’s pull_request so it should take every branch in repo

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test a workflow implementation or workflow update on a branch, before merging it, an easy way is to use the `push` trigger with the `branches` subtype:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [<BRANCH_NAME>]
```

A workflow with this implementation will trigger for every push / update to the branch you're testing (for every commit pushed after opening the pull request as well).

Then, once you have validated the workflow using this implementation, just comment or remove the trigger to use the one you wish to maintain after the merge.